# How do I share tables accross Contexts?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, cqrs

Please see the code below, which I borrowed from an online CQRS tutorial:

```
public class OrderReadContext: DbContext
    {
      public OrderReadContext() : base("name=GeekStuffSales") {

      }
      public DbSet<SalesOrder> Orders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
      modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Order");
   }
  }
  public class OrderSystemContextConfig : DbConfiguration
  {
    public OrderSystemContextConfig() {
      SetDatabaseInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer<OrderReadContext>());
    }

  }
```

and:

```
public class OrderWriteContext : DbContext
  {
    public OrderWriteContext() : base("name=GeekStuffSales")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<SalesOrder> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Order");
      modelBuilder.Entity<SalesOrder>().Ignore(s => s.LineItems);
    }
  }

  public class OrderSystemContextConfig : DbConfiguration
  {
    public OrderSystemContextConfig()
    {
      SetDatabaseInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer<OrderWriteContext>());
    }
  }
```

If I use OrderReadContext first e.g. by using GetByID, then OrderWriteContext errors the first time it is used saying: "Sales Order already exists".   If I use OrderWriteContext first e.g. by using InsertSalesOrder, then OrderReadContext errors the first time it is used saying: "Sales Order already exists".

I understand what is happening here i.e. you cannot create the same table twice.  I just want to create one database table to be used by both of these contexts.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this question is tagged with CQRS and domain-driven design I'll answer from that perspective. In a typical CQRS application, the read and write databases would be separate. And even if they resided in the same database instance the tables would be separate. This is because the read and write side schemas are likely to be different and change over the life cycle of the application.

If this was the case you would sidestep this issue altogether.

In case you find it useful, this diagram and explanation gives a reasonable conceptual architecture for a typical CQRS application. [CQRS + Event Sourcing – A Step by Step Overview](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/10/02/cqrs-step-step-guide-flow-typical-application/)

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thanks.  I hear what you are saying for this +1.  However, how would you test a CQRS application with two localdbs? For example, if you insert records into the write database, then you will not find them in the read database because replication is not set up.

Comment: I wouldn't use replication because the two databases are likely to be different. The read side is likely to be denormalised and focused on read speed. The domain database may not even be in tables. Regarding testing: You test the domain elements separately from the read side. You can create integration tests but that would require more space than I have here to explain.

Comment: My plan is to use SQL Server for the write and NoSQL for the read.  However, for testing I will have two LocalDBs that are SQL Server.  As it stands (using your approach), I will enter information into the write database and it will not be available to select from the read.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Is there a better way to approach testing with localdbS? Is there are localdb equivalent for DynamoDB/MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Run migrations (and update-database) separately for both contexts. Here is example how to work with multiple contexts: http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/entityframework/entity-framework-6-code-first-migrations-with-multiple-data-contexts